# How can I create an account resource with default parameters at the same time as creating a user resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

Apologize for the easy question.

I have nested resources

```
 resources :users do
  resources :accounts
 end
```

and I want to have an account for a new user create in the background when a user is created.

I tried

UserController

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
end
```

form_for User

```
<%= form_for([@user, @account]) do |f| %>
. . . 
<%= f.submit %>
```

But I get this error

```
 No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"accounts"}
```

I also want to pass default data in the account. "e.g. balance_in_cents => 0, etc"

Thanks for any help y'all can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user has_many accounts, in your create method in the controller you should have `@account = @user.accounts.build`.  This will then build an account for that user.

This [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) is very useful for nested forms and the rails guide for associations is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: putting in your solution I got: _No association found for name `users'. Has it been defined yet?_

Comment: adding **@account = @user.accounts.create**

the error I get now is that _the parent (@user) must be saved before calling create on the account._

Comment: In your user model you need to have has_many accounts
In your account model you need to have belongs_to user

Comment: I have that already. I've rake db:migrate'd and now the error I get when I create a user is _No association found for name `users'. Has it been defined yet?_

Answer (score 0):

Your form_for is not generating the correct route.  It often gets confused about the HTTP method.  What you need is

```
<%= form_for([@user, @account], :url => users_path, :method => :post) do |form| %>
```